# Vaadin add/remove components with buttonclick

Tags: dynamic, components, vaadin

how to check if an component is already in the layout?

I have an 4x4 gridlayout
with some buttons

one button is to show an datagrid
one to show inputfields

what I try to do is

```
MenuBar.Command tablecommand = new MenuBar.Command() {
        public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
            output.setValue("clean components");
            layout2.removeComponent(name);
            layout2.removeComponent(name2);
            layout2.removeComponent(button);
            layout2.removeComponent(cp);

            //layout2.removeComponent(grid);
            //if layout2 !contains grid

            layout2.addComponent(grid,1,2);

        }
    };
```

without check I get an exception

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already in the container
    at com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout.addComponent
```

when I click on the showgrid button the second time

the only thing I can find is ".equals(obj)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look if the component has a parent.
If yes, then it's already in place somewhere.

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#getParent--